# Security of adding a client-side iframe 

Tags: security, video, iframe

As you may know, [Pagedown](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) is a pretty nice and simple editor, but I want to extend its functionality. So far I have succeeded in doing so regarding to embedding videos, so after adding a video, you can see it in the preview window. Obviously, I had to include an `iframe` to allow such behavior, however, I'm a bit concerned about it security-wise.

Can you tell me what kind of dangers are lurking behind this use of `iframe`?. Obviously, the only purpose is to allow users to see the way his/her post would look like, so this is client-side only, but you never know when using frames.

For instance, would it be ok if I allow videos only from some domains (YouTube) or even that exposes a security vulnerability?

By the way, Google Chrome gives me this cute warning:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   file:///somethinglocaladdress from
>   frame with URL http://www.someaddress.com. Domains,
>   protocols and ports must match.

Is this something (the Google Chrome warning) I should be concerned?.

**UPDATE**: Notice my comment to phpgeek. It seems I'm covering his suggestions, but I'd like to get more answers to be sure I'm doing this right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is something you need to be too concerned about.

Regarding security-  Google actually did a pretty good job at explaining it here: http://blog.chromium.org/2008/12/security-in-depth-local-web-pages.html

Google also does outline how most other browser handle the iframe security there (at least for the older versions).

Other than that, if your question mainly relates to security vulnerabilities relating to your server, I don't think that this poses an issue.

You may also be interested in checking this page out: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Origin_inheritance_rules

Answer (score 1):

Google cross site scripting, or xss. the danger is that JavaScript in one frame can hypothetically effect the JavaScript in other frames including the parent. modern browsers are setup to prevent his to some extent which is why you got the warning  within chrome.

I would be really carefully about giving users this ability. you would be better off using a template and having users provide the URL for the source. you could then limit videos by domain if desired. YouTube provides a template for their player that will run on the parent frame if im not mistaking  and it will only work with YouTube videos. just have users provide the URL and add it to your db outside of the post

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. Actually, I'm using a template in such a way that users introduce the code that YouTube provides to embed videos, but I'm extracting width, height and video identification to use it in the frame. I wish I could use only the URL but I need to control the size of the video within my preview div.